# Typescript Compiler .js extension problem

Tags: javascript, typescript, compilation

package.json

```json
{

  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",

  "dependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/node": "^18.6.4",
    "chalk": "^5.0.1",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.19",
    "tsc-watch": "^5.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": " nodemon node --es-module-specifier-resolution=node --experimental-modules  dist/index.js",
    "build": " tsc --watch    && npm run start",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC", 
  "type": "module"
 
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
      "baseUrl": "./",
      "outDir": "./dist",
      "moduleResolution": "node",
      "importHelpers": true,
      "target": "ESNext",
      "module": "ES6",
   
      "lib": [
        "ES6",
        "dom","ESNext"
      ],
    
 
      "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": false
    },
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/node_modules/*"],

  }
```

my ts code

```js
import chalk from "chalk";
import   express  from "express"
import { getTodo } from './addTodo';

const app = express()

app.listen(4000,()=>{

    console.log(chalk.green("server is up on http://localhost:4000"))
},)

app.get("/",getTodo)
```

so when I compile like  that its givin module not found err but when I change

```
import { getTodo } from './addTodo.js';
```

like that  code every time I need to change to file extension with my hand.
I search on google to fix but they have many result have but never can fix my problem
can you help me thanks from now.

Answer (score 1):

i find solution problem was
package.json

```
 "start": " nodemon node --es-module-specifier-resolution=node --experimental-modules  dist/index.js"
```

nodemon already starting node prompt.

so we need to delete node

```
 "start": " nodemon  --es-module-specifier-resolution=node --experimental-modules  dist/index.js"
```